# Back Facing camera doesn't fill entire width of screen windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, camera, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm Making a Universal Windows Phone 8.1 app. my problem is the MediaCapture's Camera Preview in my UI's Capture Element doesn't fill the entire width of the screen when I'm using the back facing camera, however when using the front facing camera it does fill the entire width. I'm not sure what the different between the back and front facing camera is that causes this but here are the important bits of code.

```xaml
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="11*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <CaptureElement x:Name="CamCaptureElement"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</Grid>
```

the grid row and column are for the UI elements planned to be on top of the camera preview.

This is my initialization of MediaCature.

```C#
var webcamList = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
frontWebcam = (from webcam in webcamList
                where webcam.EnclosureLocation != null
                && webcam.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("front")
                select webcam).FirstOrDefault();
backWebcam = (from webcam in webcamList
                where webcam.EnclosureLocation != null
                && webcam.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("back")
                select webcam).FirstOrDefault();

mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings {
    VideoDeviceId = backWebcam.Id,
    StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
    PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview,
    AudioProcessing = AudioProcessing.Default
});

imageEncodingPropsBack = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
imageEncodingPropsBack.Width = 800;
imageEncodingPropsBack.Height = 600;

mediaCapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);

CamCaptureElement.Source = mediaCapture;

mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.PrimaryUse = CaptureUse.Photo;
```

Comment: Aspect ratio difference between cameras/screen? There is a good chance that you are expecting something like 3:4 to be equal 9:10 ...

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing.

Inside the Grid , add an image box where the final image has to come !SEt the **Stretch** property to **UNIFORM**. Dont give any height & width to the image box. What happens is when the modes are operated(landscape & potrait) , the image gets resized and its aspect ratio is maintained ! So that why in one mode you can only see it occupying half of the screen